# Docking Station Disabling/Enabling Network Connection

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, connection, docking-station

Whenever I dock my laptop onto my docking station, Windows disables my Wireless Network  Connection and enables my Wired Network Connection.  Whenever I undock my laptop, Windows disables my Wired Network Connection and enables my Wireless Network Connection.

Is there a way to disable this feature?

After Windows performs the automatic disabling/enabling, I run into errors when I try to disable the now-enabled connection, specifically *"It is not possible to disable the connection at this time.  This connection may be using one or more protocols that do not support Plug-and-Play, or it may have been initiated by another user or the system account."*

I'm assuming the latter portion of the error is true ... my network connections are being enabled/disabled under a system account.  Regardless, I'd just like to disable the feature altogether.

For reference, I'm working with Windows XP Professional on a Dell Latitude D630.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Microsoft support. There is a hotfix. This is a known issue. http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;959267&sd=rss&spid=3223

Comment: Corrected link: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;959267&sd=rss&spid=3223

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an Lenovo laptop/docking station.  The fix is to keep the same network connection in either mode, which really means not using the dock's network connection.  I did this be deleting the "1394 Connection", which is the network connection used by my dock.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system bios there is an option for LAN\WLAN swtiching. Disable that optiona and you should be all set.