# Windows 7 - Disable WiFi when connected to a wired physical network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, home-networking, power-management

I am using a sub-notebook AS1810TZ which has NO DOCKING. It has a button to turn the WiFi module off and save some power. From time to time, it is connected to the wired network and use wireless network most of the time.

I notice that the WiFi is not in use when cable is connected, but it is still active and send signals which consume power. I could rather turn it off(deep sleep) automatically once I get TCP/IP connection to same network at wired interface, and resume the WiFi module on wired disconnection.

I am asking something similar to this case 
[Docking Station Disabling/Enabling Network Connection](https://superuser.com/questions/69210/docking-station-disabling-enabling-network-connection)

I am not asking anything about metric nor priority, if you are thinking about it.
[When concurrently connected to wired and wireless ensure Windows 7 uses wired connection](https://superuser.com/questions/43387/when-concurrently-connected-to-wired-and-wireless-ensure-windows-7-uses-wired-con)

I've search on task condition, but it does not provide a option of wired/wireless network.
[When concurrently connected to wired and wireless ensure Windows 7 uses wired connection](https://superuser.com/questions/43387/when-concurrently-connected-to-wired-and-wireless-ensure-windows-7-uses-wired-con)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps check out [Wireless AutoSwitch XPV](http://www.wirelessautoswitch.com/Home.aspx).  Never used it personally but it looks like what you want.  It's got a 30 day trial, and is like $8 if you decide to buy it. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Windows task scheduler and trigger on a profile change.
Alternatively you can also trigger the disconnect (via netsh wlan disconnect) on the Windows Firewall or Hardware Driver Event (e1express for my Intel Card, see event logger for details when connecting cable). If need to disable the card you can get the command line from here: http://wlanbook.com/enable-disable-wireless-card-command-line/ (it is a little less generic)

Here is an example event trigger you can import (change usernames and my_wired_network)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2010-12-14T12:40:12.1003403</Date>
    <Author>administrator</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <EventTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <Subscription>&lt;QueryList&gt;&lt;Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational"&gt;&lt;Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational"&gt;*[System[(EventID=10000)]] and *[EventData[Data and (Data="my_wired_network")]] &lt;/Select&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/QueryList&gt;</Subscription>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>administrator</UserId>
      <LogonType>S4U</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>false</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>netsh</Command>
      <Arguments>wlan disconnect</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: Interesting, I searched for such trigger but not found useful. I'll find some time to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try 1Net. While not free it works with wifi and other connection types. http://www.accessity.com.au/1Net.htm

Comment: Can you please explain how that link is relevant? We try to prevent link rot this way - you can read more on the help article [How To Answer](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-answer).