# Disable Upon Wired Connect doesn't disconnect WiFi when connecting to wired network

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, boot-camp, wifi-driver, broadcom

The Broadcom drivers of my wireless card have a nice feature "Disable Upon Wired Connect" which worked fine previously.

[image: Disable Upon Wired Connect]

It suddenly stopped working and as a result I am connect to both wired and wireless network. Even though I've set the binding order of the wired network to highest (on top), traffic is still routed through my wireless connection unless I manually disable it.

I am using Windows 10 (64 bit, build 10.0.10586.318) on an Apple MacBook Pro Retina (through Bootcamp), I do not use OSX except for updates from Apple.

Driver version: 7.35.118.49 (6-10-2015)

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/102623/windows-7-disable-wifi-when-connected-to-a-wired-physical-network?rq=1 

The second answer could help you come to a hand-made solution.

Comment: Thanks @MadWard but my preference is to get this functionality working as it did before